# Integrating Paperclip into Rails

Tags: paperclip

I am a new Rails user and trying to integrate Paperclip into my app for the firs time. I am getting the following error message when hitting the "new post" button within my app, which is basically a blog at this point.

```
SyntaxError in Posts#new

Showing /Users/blanecordes/rails_projects/BoxScoreBuzz/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

compile error
/Users/blanecordes/rails_projects/BoxScoreBuzz/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting kEND
...end=  form_for(@post), :html=> {:multipart => true} do |f| @...
                              ^
/Users/blanecordes/rails_projects/BoxScoreBuzz/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected kDO, expecting kEND
...html=> {:multipart => true} do |f| @output_buffer.safe_conca...
                              ^
/Users/blanecordes/rails_projects/BoxScoreBuzz/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:35: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting $end
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for(@post), :html=> {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
2:   <% if @post.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
```

This is my current _form.html.erb code

```
<%= form_for(@post), :html=> {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Photo' %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :photo %><br />
  </div>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi BC00. It looks like the answer below can be accepted with a tick/check mark ("acceptance"). Accepting answers is not mandatory on Stack Overflow, but it is nice, as it rewards people for being helpful and encourages them to help again.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the first line in _form.html.erb to:

```
<%= form_for(@post, :html=> {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
```